# Firing two queries on mysql server gives error

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I am firing two select queries via jdbc PreparedStatement ,
the queries are seperated by 
semi-colon(the default seperator), 
and it gives me the following error

**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select inq.preffered_date as 'dom' , inq.id from assigned_inquiries ai join inqu' at line 1**

**select inq.preffered_date as .........** is where the second query begins.

Edit-> the query

```
select
    ms.next_date_of_meeting as 'dom',
    ms.inquiry_id as 'id'
from
    assigned_inquiries ai,
    meeting_status ms
where
    ai.representative_id = 1
    and (
        ai.status = 'postponed'
        or ai.status = 'remeeting'
    )
    and ai.inquiry_id = ms.inquiry_id
    and ms.next_date_of_meeting between '2012-1-1' and '2012-12-31'
    and ms.created_on = (select max(created_on) from meeting_status where inquiry_id = ms.inquiry_id);

select
    inq.preffered_date as 'dom',
    inq.id
from
    assigned_inquiries ai
    join inquiry inq on ai.inquiry_id = inq.id
where
    ai.representative_id = 1
    and ai.status = 'new'
    and inq.preffered_date between '2012-1-1' and '2012-12-31';
```

Is it possible to execute two queries at a time.
Help Please.

Comment: It doesn't look to me like the two queries is the problem. Can you post your queries?

Comment: I don't suppose it has anything to do with "Preferred_date" being misspelled does it?

Comment: i dont think you can send two select statements in a single prepared statement.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: I noticed that as well, but based on the error message, it doesn't look like that's the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute several statements at once with MySQL. However, this feature is disabled by default. To enable it, use the property `allowMultiQueries`. See the MySQL documentation for JDBC driver for more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/salesorder?allowMultiQueries=true       is that the correct format of mentioning property